VBA macro to login to Yahoo Finance
Recently Yahoo Finance began requiring a userid and password to download historical stock price data. I have an account previously used as macro to download the data I needed. If I try using this macro I receive a User is not logged in the response to my query.
How do I modify my objRequest to pass the userid and password?
tickerURL = "https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/download/" & stockTicker & _
    "?period1=" & startDate & _
    "&period2=" & endDate & _
    "&interval=" & frequency & "&events=history"

Set objRequest = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
With objRequest
    .Open "GET", tickerURL, False
    .send
    .waitForResponse
    resultFromYahoo = .ResponseText
End With

I am able to login to Yahoo with this:
Dim http As Object
Dim url As String
Dim params As String

' Create the XMLHTTP object
Set http = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")

' Define the URL and parameters
url = "https://login.yahoo.com/"
params = "username=myUseris&passwd=myPassword"

' Open the connection and send the request
http.Open "POST", url, False
http.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
http.send params

' Clean up
Set http = Nothing


I wonder if you need to obtain the cookie(s) from the login and inject them into the download operation. Could you look into that?

Use Yahoo V8 - Chart api to get the data in JSON format and parse it using Tim Hall's JSon Parser where there is a sample code for getting Yahoo historical data
